# CURL alternative in Python, in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, curl, python-requests

I have a question about Python to use SSL two-way authentication, our development environment is Windows 10

We are currently using Git Bash curl for initial testing, and the sample code is as follows

```bash
curl -v --cacert CA.pem --cert server.crt --key server.key -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <Token>" -d "{}" https://sample.com/api/Accounts
```

There was success in getting the data, but we used Python [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and used the conversion site Convert curl commands (https://curlconverter.com/) to get like this

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <Token>',
}

cert = ('server.crt', 'server.key')

json_data = {}

response = requests.post('https://sample.com/api/Accounts', headers=headers, json=json_data, cert=cert, verify='CA.pem')
```

The result is an error

```bash
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, '遠端主機已強制關閉一個現存的連線。', None, 10054, None))
```

I need a way to do the same thing in Python. Is there an alternative to cURL in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I never had much success with certificates and requests for `Python` using Windows. If I were you, I would use a `subprocess` and call *git, bash* directly. This might not look that nice, but is easily portable, given that you have *git, bash* installed (which is the default under Windows I think). Here is a code snippet, that might help you:

```
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe","C:/Users/userName/Documents/dev/curl_get_data.sh"], 
                     bufsize=-1, 
                     executable=None, 
                     stdin=None, 
                     stdout=None, 
                     stderr=None, 
                     preexec_fn=None, 
                     close_fds=True, 
                     shell=False, 
                     cwd="C:/Users/userName/Documents/dev", 
                     )
```

In the shell script `curl_get_data.sh` you can use your normal curl syntax!

Comment: Thanks your answer. I did think about using this method.

Comment: I hope to find other implementations using the python suite